# Optional framework in Cocoapods depending on iOS version

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a local `cocoapodA` with has a dependency `cocoapodB` set via `s.dependency 'cocoapodB'`.
In the podspec of `cocoaPodB` there is a definition for framework via `s.vendored_frameworks   = 'MyFramework.framework'`

The problem here is that `MyFramework.framework` only runs on iOS12+
When I try to compile for iOS11 for example, I get an error `Library not loaded, image not found`. This lets me believe I need to set the framework as optional as you would do in `Link Binary with Libraries`.

[image: Link Binary With Libraries - Optional status]
The question is, how can I set this as optional via cocoapods for iOS11 and lower?
Is this possible or should I look for another solution?

Comment: Shouldn't `UserNotifications.framework` set as `weak_frameworks`, and not as framework? Can you change cocoaPodB where it's set? Is it a mistake on their end? What is its minimum iOS version, iOS12 then?

Comment: @Larme You are right, I should use `s.weak_frameworks` instead of `s.vendored_frameworks` here. This is the correct answer. thank you